# How to add post with category and tags through SQL query, is it real?

Tags: c#, mysql, wordpress

I have a simple program on C#, there I have a few textboxes:

`title, slug, post-text, category, tags`

When a user of this simple program fills textboxes and click on button called `Publish`, my SQL query is sent to the database.

For now I have an SQL query that send Post title + Post text without cat's and tags:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO wp_posts (post_author, post_date, post_date_gmt,
              post_content, post_title, post_excerpt, post_status,
              comment_status, ping_status, post_password, post_name, 
              to_ping, pinged, post_modified, post_modified_gmt, 
              post_content_filtered, post_parent, guid, menu_order,
              post_type, post_mime_type, comment_count)" +

             "VALUES (1,@date,@date, @Content, @Title,'', 'publish', 'open', 
                      'open','', @Postname,'','',@date,@date,'','0','','0','post','','');";
```

This is the working query. But I need a solution to add categories and tags.

WordPress database structure is here https://deliciousbrains.com/tour-wordpress-database/

I understand what I need to send with my query, but I can't do it because of my low level of SQL.

Comment: I would highly suggest creating a stored procedure then you can start looking at some google examples on how to use create a parameterized Select query in `MySql` this is very hard to debug in it's current state not to mention it's very poor approach to use concatenation when building Sql Querys google how to create parameterized query in wordpress as well

Comment: I'm not sure what it is that you are trying to do. If you are using WordPress, in general you will need to use PHP, not C#. However, are you trying to do something outside of WordPress? If so then yes, you can add categories and tags: have you tried sending an `INSERT` for those things? I imagine they will have their own tables, and the primary keys will `auto-increment` so you don't need to worry about setting them yourself.

Comment: You could try to set some categories and some tags for one temporary post on wordpress (you can keep it as draft). After that, in your database, search in the tables *postmeta*, *terms*, *termmeta*, for your post ID, what are the relations involved in *categories* and *terms* within this post. It is just an idea… after that it could be easier for you to build your queries for your app (programed in C#).